# Unity 3D - Transforming beetween worlds/planes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Let's say I want to replicate Planeshifting from Legacy of Kain: Soul Reaver in Unity.

There are 2 realms: **Spectral realm** and **Material realm**.

The **Spectral realm** is based on the **Material realm**, only has the geometry distorted and certain objects fade out/become non-interactive.

In Soul Reaver, it is used as means to go to areas where you normally wouldn't be able to in Material (distorting geometry), to use other powers (such as going through grates).

My question is: Is it even possible at all to implement this in Unity 3D? (I would need the Scene(level) or the objects to have 2 states somehow that I could switch beetween/distort to real-time.)

Comment: Interesting. I was looking for the same thing. Look at [link](https://blog.eu.playstation.com/2012/10/12/behind-the-classics-legacy-of-kain-soul-reaver/) for the interview with the game director Hennig. The interesting part follows this para _Our second challenge, of course, was figuring out how to store two sets of data for the spectral and material realms, and how to implement the real-time morph between the two environments._

Comment: I didn't do anything about this topic after all because other things, but I really feel like that if the world was made in a modelling program, such as Blender, it'd be possible to have animations for the material/spectral realms, same with objects and just write some code to call those animations, disable the objects and some logic for the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call this a rather advanced topic and there are multiple ways of accomplishing a at least similar effect.

But to answer your actual question straight away -  **Yes it is possible.**

And here are some approaches i would take (i guess that would be your next question ;))

- **The easiest way** is obviously having game object which have their   collider and renderer disabled (or the whole object) when "changing
  realms".   But this for sure isn't the best-looking way of doing it,
  even tho a lot of motion blur or other image effect could help.

  (Depending on what shaders you use, animating the alpha value can
  create a fading effect as well)
- **The more advanced way** would be the actual manipulation of vertices (changing the object). There are quite a few tutorials on
  how to change the geometry of object.   Take a look at Mesh() in the
  official documentation:
  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

  > A class that allows creating or modifying meshes from scripts.
- **Another way (didn't try) thats rather easy** would be using shape keys.   I don't know which Software you use to create your
  world/models but blender has this function which allows you to define
  a base shape, then edit the verticies in blender and save it as a
  second (or more) shapes.   Unity can blend smoothly between those
  shapes as being shown in this video:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vvNV1VeXhk

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be possible in Unity3D, but your question is quite general. You could try something like having 2 models per GameObject (perhaps as children or fields on the script) and disabling 1 of them depending on which realm the player is in. You could have 2 scenes for each level and switch between them, though that might be too slow. You could see if there are any plugins/assets that allow you to define 2 models and morph between them. There are probably a number of other routes you could take, but I can't really help more until you've chosen a path.

Comment: Concerning your second thoughts about two scenes, an alternative would be to have two scenes within the scene. That is you have one level at 0,0,0 and another one far enough not to be seen like 1000,0,0. On switch, you set one level off and the other on and move the player to the corresponding position (x + 1000 , y, z).

Comment: The problem with the first theory would be animation - how would I create the "transforming" or "distorting"/"morphing" effect?
The last one, again, there's no real way to have a smooth transition, and would be more resource hungry.